# Why does web UI show different durations in Jobs and Stages pages?

Tags: apache-spark, profiling

I am running a dummy spark job that does the exactly same set of operations in every iteration. The following figure shows 30 iterations, where each job corresponds to one iteration. It can be seen the duration is always around 70 ms except for job 0, 4, 16, and 28. The behavior of job 0 is expected as it is when the data is first loaded. 
[image: 30 Iterations]

But when I click on job 16 to enter its detailed view, the duration is only 64 ms, which is similar to the other jobs, the screen shot of this duration is as follows:

[image: detailed view]

I am wondering where does Spark spend the (2000 - 64) ms on job 16?

Comment: Cau post your code?

Answer (score 2):

*Gotcha!* That's exactly the very same question I asked myself **few days ago**. I'm glad to share the findings with you (hoping that when I'm lucking understanding others chime in and fill the gaps).

---

The difference between what you can see in Jobs and Stages pages is the time required to schedule the stage for execution.

In Spark, a single job can have one or many stages with one or many tasks. That creates an execution plan.

By default, a Spark application runs in FIFO scheduling mode which is to execute one Spark job at a time regardless of how many cores are in use (you can check it in the web UI's Jobs page).

[image]

Quoting [Scheduling Within an Application](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application):

> By default, Spark’s scheduler runs jobs in FIFO fashion. Each job is divided into "stages" (e.g. map and reduce phases), and the first job gets priority on all available resources while its stages have tasks to launch, then the second job gets priority, etc. If the jobs at the head of the queue don’t need to use the whole cluster, later jobs can start to run right away, but if the jobs at the head of the queue are large, then later jobs may be delayed significantly.

You should then see how many tasks a single job will execute and divide it by the number of cores the Spark application have assigned (you can check it in the web UI's Executors page).

[image]

That will give you the estimate on how many "cycles" you may need to wait before all tasks (and hence the jobs) complete.

NB: That's where dynamic allocation comes to the stage as you may sometimes want more cores later and start with a very few upfront. That's what the conclusion I offered to my client when we noticed a similar behaviour.

I can see that all the jobs in your example have 1 stage with 1 task (which make them very simple and highly unrealistic in production environment). That tells me that your machine could have got busier at different intervals and so the time Spark took to schedule a Spark job was longer but once scheduled the corresponding stage finished as the other stages from other jobs. I'd say it's a beauty of profiling that it may sometimes (often?) get very unpredictable and hard to reason about.

Just to shed more light on the internals of how web UI works. web UI uses a bunch of Spark listeners that collect current status of the running Spark application. There is at least one Spark listener per page in web UI. They intercept different execution times depending on their role.

Read about [org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) interface and review different callback to learn about the variety of events they can intercept.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I am trying to understand the information on spark UI and this is very helpful. I have 84 tasks in one stage, 80 cores at hand. 84/80 gives a little less than one. What does this mean now!

Comment: It means that executing 84 tasks will take one round with 80 tasks at once and the remaining 4 tasks are going to be scheduled after one of the 80 tasks finishes. And that's until all 84 tasks are completed.